# Why is symfony2 web profiler panel not changing?

Tags: php, debugging, symfony, profiler

I'm trying to use the web profiler to debug symfony but the panel that controls what I'm debugging is not changing. For whatever reason its only staying on the request panel, however I need to check out the entity debugger panel. How can I get this to work and what files should I look at?

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem by using nginx + php-fpm. If you're using the same configuration, than you can solve it by adding $args to the end try_files line in nginx.conf:

```
# ...
location / {
    try_files $uri /app_dev.php?$args
}
```